# Нарушение прав доступа при чтении из файла

Tags: c, файлы

Создал файл в папке с проектом. Запускаю следующий код:

```
FILE * f;
char ch;
f = (FILE *) fopen("results.txt", "r");
ch = getc(f);
printf("%s", ch);
fclose(f);
```

Программа аварийно завершает работу с ошибкой:

> "0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу 0x00000074."

Хотя если открыть файл для записи всё записывается нормально. Пробовал запускать программу от имени администратора —  ошибка не исчезает.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём тут дело?

Comment: @iproger, хоть ошибка и в формате в printf (о чкм Вам @KoVadim написал), но результат fopen проверять никогда не мешает.

     #include <sysexits.h>
     ...
     if (!(f = fopen("results.txt", "r"))) {
        perror("fopen (\"results.txt\", \"r\")");
        exit(EX_DATAERR);
     }
     ...

Comment: я проверяю, но здесь просто выдернутый код, я тестировал без лишнего кода. А exit не понятно зачем, если можно делать return 0 из main

Comment: @iproger, конечно, из `main` можно и `return EX_DATAERR;`

Почему не -1, а EX_DATAERR? Потому что это ошибка в данных, переданных пользователем.

Правильные (общепринятые по крайней мере в \*nix) коды возврата программы см. в `sysexits.h`.

Comment: @avp, понятно, спасибо. Просто библиотеку подключать, жалко нагружать программу) Нас в универе учат кодить на СИ без лишнего, на каждом байте препод задрачивается. Я вообще не очень люблю так, наоборот хочу чтобы код понятен был, чтобы удобен был: по больше функций, структур (вместо нескольких переменных) и тд. Поэтому всё-таки воспользуюсь библиотекой этой)

Comment: @iproger, функция `exit` (наряду с fopen, printf и огромным множество других) находится обычно в `libc`, которая почти во всех ОС разделяемая (.so или .dll) и ее код непосредственно в состав загрузочного модуля не входит. Единственный загруженный в память экземпляр используется всеми программами, которые выполняются в данный момент.

Конечно, несколько байт "переходника" linker добавит, но не думаю, что это критично.

Comment: Понятно, спасибо большое.

Comment: @iproger, ещё одна деталь: `char ch = getc(f);` - распространённая ошибка. Функция `getc()` возвращает `int`, и читая ей в `char` можно огрести немало проблем. В частности, не обнаружить ошибку чтения или признак конца файла.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Проблема не в чтении файла. Проблема в строке

```
printf("%s", ch);
```

дело в том, что ch - это символ (char), а printf будет печатать строку (параметр `%s`). А что такое строка? это просто последовательность символов до первого нулевого. Вот оно и начиная с адреса локальной переменной бежит по памяти до первого нулевого символа.

Comment: Спасибо большое, вот почему нормальный отладчик не сделали, который указал бы мне, что "Возможно я не правильно передал параметр %s". Просто как-то отложились s,d,lf,f. Про c  и забыл совсем. Спасибо!

Comment: судя с того, что ошибка звучит как "0xC0000005", Вы пользуетесь майкрософтовским компилятором. А он такой.

А вот gcc, если включить нормальный уровень предупреждений (хотя бы `-Wall`), ещё на этапе компиляции будет критиковать:

    warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
     printf("%s", ch);

настоятельно рекомендую включить предупреждения!

Comment: Да, я пользуюсь майкрасофтом( Надо попробовать gcc, спасибо